# 405 method not found PATCH [google cloud composer airflow patch rest api] -JAVA

Tags: java, airflow-api

**Airflow patch rest api is not working for JAVA version 11.**
Here is the code snippet.

```
Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
params.put("state", "failed");

GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = null;
try {
    googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
String url = "airflow url";
HttpCredentialsAdapter credentialsAdapter = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(googleCredentials);
HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new ApacheHttpTransport().createRequestFactory(credentialsAdapter);
HttpRequest request=null;
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
HttpContent content = new JsonHttpContent(jsonFactory, params);

try {
    request = requestFactory.buildPatchRequest((new GenericUrl(url)), content);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JsonObjectParser parser = new JsonObjectParser(GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance());
request.setParser(parser);
HttpHeaders httpHeader = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeader.setContentType("application/json");
httpHeader.setAccept("application/json");
        
request.setHeaders(httpHeader);
HttpResponse response = null;
try {
    response = request.execute();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    System.out.println(response.parseAsString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The google cloud composer is trying the redirect the airflow_url to service logic(https://`cloud_url`/_signin?continue=?airflow_url) where i am getting the below error
**com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 405 Method Not Allowed PATCH**

the same request with python is working fine(https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/access-airflow-api#make_calls_to_airflow_rest_api)

(PATCH) Airflow REST API(https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/update_dag_run_state)

```
url: https://airflow.apache.org/api/v1/dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns/{dag_run_id}
body: {
  "state": "success"
}
'Content type': application/json
```

Comment: The above code is working fine without the `HttpHeaders` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
params.put("state", "failed");

GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = null;
try {
    googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
String url = "airflow url";
HttpCredentialsAdapter credentialsAdapter = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(googleCredentials);
HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new ApacheHttpTransport().createRequestFactory(credentialsAdapter);
HttpRequest request=null;
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
HttpContent content = new JsonHttpContent(jsonFactory, params);

try {
    request = requestFactory.buildPatchRequest((new GenericUrl(url)), content);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

HttpResponse response = null;
try {
    response = request.execute();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    System.out.println(response.parseAsString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).